# PostgreSQL can't insert 100 million characters into TEXT column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 15. It is installed in AWS RDS. This table has a `TEXT` column.

When I try to insert medium text length (several thousand characters), I have no problems and it works. However, when I try to insert a large text (100 million characters, 54 Mb `.txt` file), I get no errors, but the column in that row remains empty - the data is not inserted.

Data has no special characters etc., just digits and a-zA-Z.

How can I insert this amount of characters into a table? Or should I store data in a different way?

Comment: 100 Million characters even if all characters require 4 bytes will fit into a `text` column. This is most likely a problem with your program code that tries to insert that string. Or maybe Amazon's Postgres fork behaves differently.

Comment: Most likely the problem is in the code you are using to insert that data. Please include it.

Comment: Not reproducible.  `create table j1 as select string_agg(md5(x::text),'') from generate_series(1,3125000) f(x);`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

> The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case of character. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1. Long strings are compressed by the system automatically, so the physical requirement on disk might be less. Very long values are also stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid access to shorter column values. In any case, the longest possible character string that can be stored is about 1 GB. (The maximum value that will be allowed for n in the data type declaration is less than that. It wouldn't be useful to change this because with multibyte character encodings the number of characters and bytes can be quite different. If you desire to store long strings with no specific upper limit, use text or character varying without a length specifier, rather than making up an arbitrary length limit.)

It would be better if you can describe your use case a little bit more to include a recommendation.